# CGRect has no member 'right'? why CGRect is not working probably?

Tags: swift, syntax-error, frame, cgrect

so am following a guy on youtube who wrote in the CGrect:

```
nameLabel.frame = CGRect( x: userProfileImage.right + 5,
```

this code is supposed to put the nameLabel to the right of the userProfileImage but when I use the same code it tells me `Value of type 'UIImageView' has no member 'right'`

can someone help me figure out why it is not working?

[image: My Code]

[image: Youtube tutorial]

the black screen is the code of the guy on youtube with no errors, the white is mine. Same Xcode version.

Comment: Did the person have an extension to `UIImageView` or `UIView`?  (e.g. `extension UIView {var right: CGFloat { self.frame.width + self.frame.origin.x }}`)

Comment: It's always confusing when someone adds an extension that doesn't add any new functionality but it only renames existing functionality.
However, considering this code is not using constraints, it is probably very old. I would guess 7-9 years old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `UIView` does not have such a member, this guy is probably using an extension or library. Try `userProfileImage.frame.maxX`.